# Moderators on Area51 sites

Tags: support, area-51, moderators, 10k-tools

I know that Stack Exchange sites need moderators.

It takes quite a long time to get 10k reputation and because of this, I want to know if this limit is the same on [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) sites. It seems, that public beta sites have the 10k limit but what about the private beta sites?

Or is this not a problem because the private beta is limited to certain users (and it would not need moderators because of that) in any case and they can get the required reputation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me try to clear up your confusion a bit.

> I know that Stack Exchange sites need moderators.

Well, actually they need *moderation*. This comes in multiple forms: regular users, even with only 15 reputation, can *upvote* and *flag* posts. See the [moderation-oriented privileges](/help/privileges?tab=moderation). With more reputation, you'll be able to perform other important task like commenting*, downvoting, editing and closing. The 10k you refer to is to have access to moderator *tools*, which used to be a much bigger deal than it is now. (Back then, some of the flags now handled by ♦ moderators were handled by 10k users.) In this way, by earning reputation, *everyone* can be a moderator, and 10k reputation is not necessary for all but the advanced tasks; with only 3k you've got a good set of moderation tools at your disposal.

On smaller sites, it's harder to earn reputation, and on beta-sites the [reputation thresholds are lowered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/295232). You can close vote at 500 reputation already, edit at 1000 and the moderator tools privilege is set at 2k reputation. For Area 51, the reputation requirements are yet different; they can be found by scrolling down here: https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq. Because of its nature, Area 51 needs less moderation than most regular Q&A sites. Note that reputation on Area 51 counts for the entire site, which includes all proposals. Only when a proposal is promoted to a private beta will it count as a separate site.

Now the ♦ is the another form of moderation; that's a small group of users (commonly called 'moderators') elected by the community or appointed by Stack Exchange staff. They have some [additional powers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) (and responsibilities).